# How do I map Alt+Space in Linux with xmodmap?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap, puppylinux

I am trying to map Alt+Space to Escape in Puppy Linux. Specifically, this is for vim, but I could not get it to work there. So, I thought I better try to do it globally, but I have no idea what is the key code for Alt+Space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't: xmodmap can manipulate modifier-keys and manipulate key-codes, but <kbd>Alt</kbd> is not one of the predefined modifiers (i.e., <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>).

<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> are treated specially, and allow the sort of manipulation which you have in mind.

You *can* assign <kbd>Alt</kbd> to one of the placeholders `mod1`, `mod2`, `mod3`, `mod4` or `mod5`.  That lets programs see <kbd>Alt</kbd> as a modifier, but does not provide the the ability to treat it as one of the shiftable-features.

Further reading:

- [xmodmap - utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in X](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html)

Comment: Well, I guess that's pretty sad... Thanks though.